# get Book ID and show book details

Tags: java, file

my "AllBookRecords.txt" file is this:

```
Name        Date        Number
second   2002   22
thired   2003   33
fourth   2004   44
fifth   2005   55
```

and my search button code is this:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String bookid=jTextField2.getText();
    File f=new File("D:\\AllBookRecords.txt");
    try{
        FileReader Bfr=new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader Bbr=new BufferedReader(Bfr);
        String bs;
        while( (bs=Bbr.readLine()) != null ){
            if( bs.contains(bookid ) ){
                String[] Ust=bs.split("   ");
                String Bname=Ust[0];
                String Bdate=Ust[1];
                jLabel1.setText("Book Found,    "+ Bname + "    " + Bdate);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

when i enter for example 33 and click the button, the result show only last record like this:
fifth   2005

why?
Thank you for help!

Comment: Actually I have no idea how this code can show `fifth 2005 55`. Print `bookid` inside the method to make sure it is indeed 33. And try to use debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not a real solution to you problem but the way you search for book by book ids can easily produce errors.

You are using `String.contains(bookid)` to check if the complete line contains the book id.

For example: If your book id is `20` the first line would match because the String `2002` contains the book id `20`:

```
"second   2002   22".contains("20"); // returns true because 2002 'contains' 20
```

To fix this problem you should split the string first and then compare only the book ids.

**update:** A possible fix to this would look like:

```
while( (bs=Bbr.readLine()) != null ){
    String[] Ust=bs.split("   ");
    String Bname=Ust[0];
    String Bdate=Ust[1];
    String id = Ust[2];
    if (id.equals(bookid.trim()) // only compare Id's + you should always trim user input
        jLabel1.setText("Book Found,    "+ Bname + "    " + Bdate);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you Explain more? how i fix this problem?

Comment: Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter id:");
        int idS=in.nextInt();
        File f=new File("C:\\SearchFile.txt");
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;

        while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] st=s.split(" ");
            String id=st[0];
            String name=st[1];
            String mark=st[2];

            if(id.equals(String.valueOf(idS))){
                
                System.out.println(id+" "+name+" "+mark);
            }
        }

Comment: My SearchFile.txt is this:
1 max 26
2 brown 93